# Is it possible to prevent php session from destroying when you close browser?

Tags: php, session

We want to use sessions instead of cookies for keeping track of a few things. However, when I close my browser, and I reopen a page to echo a session var, it doesn't exist (which is how it is suppose to be). Is it possible to prevent this from happening with some magic or anything?

This is not a duplicate question, all I see are people wanting to destroy sessions, I want to do the opposite and retain the session for as long as possible.

Any knowledge would be appreciated.

Comment: Session uses cookie to store its ID to the client. You actually are using both. How about finding client's data, like, IP, browser name, OS name, math score, electricity bill, dog's name or whatever which is moar complicated than keeping users to reconnect once if they remove the cookie you've stored in their browser?

Comment: @Chay22 A session id should be used basically. All other indices like IP can be compared for additional security. Actually you can turn off cookies as primary session id storage by `ini_set("session.use_cookies", 0); ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way of doing this is with a database, you can mimic or control php sessions and store them in a database instead of in a file ( as normal ).  Then once you have control of the data you can base renewing session via the ip address or better yet by login.

So say a user logs in and then you need to store some data, you store that in the session but php will store it in your database table ( when configured correctly ).  Latter the user comes back, initially any visitor would get a fresh session, however once they login you would be able to retrieve the past session they had.  You generally don't have much control on if or when a client will delete expired cookies.

This topic is too extensive to put just a few pieces of example code but I did find this small article on the topic.

http://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database/

The guts of it is to use this function, `session_set_save_handler`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Once you have control of the data you can do whatever you want, however I would caution you about relying only on the IP address and it would be preferable to use a login system for something like this to prevent serving the session up to the wrong visitor.

You cannot reliably control what happens on the client side, even using a separate cookie would not be reliable and would have the disadvantage of storing data on the client where it could be accessed instead of keeping it on your server.  Sessions are controlled by cookies but the data in them remains on your server, the cookie just identifies the client.

- As a side note, I personally dislike using sessions at all. It may be possible to store what you need in the url, then it can be bookmarked.  The classic example would be input for a search form ( via $_GET ) or for paging purposes.  There is nothing wrong with doing this if it's not secure data. The problem with sessions is if the data is for a page such as my "classic example" or for paging you get only one session, so you would only be able to have one set of search data at a time, in the url you could have several sets of search data open at once.  That said it does largely depend on what you need to save or persist.

Comment: That is what I figured, thank you for confirming. Apologies to everyone for this question, it seems it's downvotageddon.

Comment: It's probably down voted because there are security implications with this, such as someone stealing or mimicking a clients session.  The level of security largely depends on the "data" you need to store.  Some things like letting a user choose what CSS style to use on your site are probably not that critical but other things could be.

Comment: Yes, no it's more for marketing. Not entirely evil, but yes I know for sure there could be some implications if this were possible. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Security related information/actions like changing passwords etc. should of course never rely on sessions since the id could be hitchhiked. Such operation should always be confirmed by password (stored as hash, transmitted via SSL). "Downvotageddon" :) seems to become a standard on SO at some specific daytime. As I understand the question, the problem was that session cookies get deleted on closing the browser. You have to rewrite it as persistent cookie. However, custom settings (or tools like ccleaner) can delete them anyway. But that's user's own responsibility.

Comment: Sure, I've handled sessions this way many times.  Currently at my work we use a commercial product that does this exact thing.  Storing session in the DB, but it's not to had to implement yourself.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, the idea is to persist a session.  The only reliable way to do this is to control it and not rely on the client at all.  Sessions can be wiped if a user manually logs out of the site, otherwise I would preserve them for a few days.  All cookies aside..... in short the question is `Is it possible to prevent php session from destroying when you close browser` the answer is `Yes` but not by relying on the session cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the session cookie manually.

```
$lifetime=60*60; // duration in seconds
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session.gc_maxlifetime` and `session_set_cookie_params`, i.e.:

```
// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 1 Year
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600 * 24 * 365);

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 1 Year
session_set_cookie_params(3600 * 24 * 365);

session_start();
```

---

**Note:**

- You can also change the session options globally by editing `php.ini` -
  [Session configuration options](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)

Answer (score -1):

PHP sessions use `session cookies`.  Browsers have their own ways of dealing with them but they all consider them to be trash if you close the browser.

Session cookies are not and can not be made persistent.  If you need persistent cookies, just use a regular cookie to save a user identification code that your server would recognize, and save their session information in a database or flat file indexed on that id code.

Note that accumulating sessions on the server progressively causes important performance and security concerns.

Note on other answers:  All of them mention ways to extend the session cookie expiration which will not overcome the regular behavior when you close your browser window.